# Why is the current in the main circuit lower with Transistor vs without it?

Tags: transistors, npn

I'm using EveryCircuit to start studying electronics and I have a question:

See image A and B. Why is the current in the A way lower than B? I was assuming it should be the same since the transistor is just switching it on.

I'm trying to make sense of this result.

thanks

A)
[image]

B)
[image]

**Edit:**

Answering  jsotola comment:

I guess you mean to invert the collector and emitter terminals, which I did and I get same results.

[image]

Comment: the transistor is incorrectly connected

Comment: Also, the base current isn't limited, so a real transistor would simply burn out the very moment the button is pressed.

Comment: @janka actually I was trying that in real breadboard with a real transistor, I was intrigued why the led didn't turn on when I gave up and removed the components from breadboard. When I try to remove the transistor  I burned my thumb and indicator very, very badly. Price of lack of knowledge...

Comment: @RollRoll Never drive the base-emitter of a BJT with a direct voltage supply or battery. You always want a current limiting resistor in there, somewhere. It's basically a diode. And like all diodes, you pretty much want a resistor present somewhere in series with it, if you use a voltage supply. The resistor can be at the base side or it can be at the emitter side. But it has to be somewhere in the loop.

Comment: Aside from the lack of base resistor and running the transistor in reverse mode, the current is really not "way" less in A, it's about 3.3% less, pretty negligible. The difference is accounted for by the small drop across the transistor (0.232V).

Comment: I think a MOSFET would suit your needs better. It is controlled by voltage instead of current (so no need for a resistor in the base), and it's way more ideal to be used as a switch than a BJT.

Answer (score 3):

I know that you must connect everything up correctly in a circuit in order to make things work. But I want you to realize that there are two main classifications of schematics.

1. A schematic designed to show all of the physical connections so that you know how to construct it; and,
2. A schematic designed to communicate how it works and functions.

These are very different goals. The first one helps a builder of circuits who doesn't really care to understand them, but just needs to know the exact details required in putting it together correctly so that it operates as designed. The second one helps a designer communicate to other designers how the design functions. In this latter case, it's not so important to show all the connections.

Since you need to understand what you did and do not really need to know how to build another one, let's look at a schematic designed to communicate to designers.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYGVtj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The above two schematics are equivalent. Notice that I've remove all the wiring to voltage sources and simply placed the right voltage at the right place. This helps avoid distracting wiring and makes you focus on what the circuit actually looks like to a designer.

(I've added a little dashed box around an NPN to highlight the fact that there are actually *two* diodes in the NPN transistor. These diodes aren't exactly mirror images of each other: one is designed differently than the other one. But this lets you see that if you wire it "upside down" so to speak, it can still operate. Just... differently.)

The left side schematic "looks weird" to a designer. The NPN seems wired up backwards. It looks like the LED current would have to flow ***against*** the diode direction indicated in the standard BJT diagram. But the right side diagram shows the arrangement more clearly. And if you look over the dashed box illustration of the NPN in the upper left corner, you can see that the base is indeed forward-biased -- except that it is forward-biased with respect to the collector, not the emitter.

This isn't a total disaster. The NPN will work like that, too. It will just have a much worse active mode \$\beta\$.

So looking at the right side schematic, you can see that you've turned the emitter into the collector and the collector into the emitter. (Which is fine, just not often done.)

The real problem here is that your base is set to a hard \$1.25\:\text{V}\$ across the "new" base-emitter junction. This means there is no current limiting taking place. So ***lots*** of base current will flow. As a result, the "new" collector will be very close to the "new" emitter voltage (ground, basically.) This "new" collector will also be forward biased relative to the base.

So everything kind of works. Except for the one huge problem that you are missing any current limit to the forward-biased base-emitter and base-collector junctions. As a result, very very large currents will flow from the base. And this means very, very big dissipation in the BJT. So it should get VERY HOT.

---

Put a resistor in the base-emitter loop.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzRCxa.png)</sup>

Either one of the above two will work. Try them both out.

The left side one works because the emitter current is \$I_\text{LED}=\frac{1.25\:\text{V}-700\:\text{mV}}{27\:\Omega}\approx 20\:\text{mA}\$. The BJT is *not* saturated in that case. The right side one works because the BJT is in fact saturated and the LED current is about what you figured out in the first place, limited by the value of \$R_1\$.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring all the issues with component orientation and proper biasing, I'll try to address what seems to be the core misunderstanding.

A transistor in saturation does act as a switch in ideal simplified terms, but ideal components don't exist and no component is without some resistance. How much resistance exactly will depend on the specific component and configuration.

Adding **anything** in series with a circuit other than a current source will increase total resistance and decrease total current (assuming a fixed input voltage). Even a longer wire will have an impact. The question is does the impact negatively impact the design function?

You're only going from 21.2mA to 20.5mA in your example. For most  circuits, a difference of 0.7mA is negligible. You could easily see the same 3% difference in practice by swapping identically rated components since most passives have a 5-10% tolerance. The difference you're seeing is normal, and probably won't even create a visible difference in LED brightness.